# Apex 20.1 Complex What-If Scenario Analysis

Tags: plsql, time-series, dependencies, oracle-apex

i am facing an complex issue where when event changes on a time series (year basis) it has an minor or mayor affect on the other following events and finally on the defined target. Meaning that when one event changes on the monetary status or any other status then to following events needs to be changed afterwards since all the events are connected and dependend (and are in relations) and belong to a bigger picture. I am talking here about running some what-if analysis on changing data.

Does anyone has an idea on how to approach this problem in an Oracle Apex workaround with PL/SQL or can recommend a way to start or tackle this problem since I need faced such issue.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is difficult to understand.  Can you provide a specific example?

Comment: have you thought about on update triggers?